# How to prove that a certain polynomial with integer coefficients has no real roots

Tags: real-analysis

In a [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1766743) to which I had given a solution, I had not been able to prove **in a rigorous way** (i.e., without any recourse to any approximation) that polynomial:

$$f(x) = 4 - 8\,x + 4\,x^2 + 4\,x^4 - 6\,x^5 - 4\,x^6 + 6\,x^7 + 4\,x^8 - x^{10} - 4\,x^{11} - x^{12} + 2\,x^{13} + x^{14}\\
$$

has no real roots, which amounts to say that $\forall x, \ f(x)>0$.

(the curve of $f$ is **visibly** above $x$ axis for all $x$, as can be seen on the figure, but I am looking for "clean" arguments...).

I have made several attempts, especially by trying to find simpler polynomial expressions $g(x)$ such that $g(x) \leq f(x)$, to use complex variable techniques (Rouché's theorem...), etc. unsuccessfully.

Has somebody a solution ?
[image]

Comment: The minimum value of this very high degree polynomial is $\leq \frac{1}{2}$, so one doesn't have much room at all here.

Comment: @Travis Yes, and the derivative is not factorizable... but meanwhile loup blanc has given a solution using a Sturm sequence.

Comment: It is sad that on Math StackExchange, some people (may be always the same) downvote questions (and even propose to close them) in an anonymous manner. Maybe, in the present case, he/she/they has/have not understood the issue; then, why not ask precisions in a preliminary step...

Comment: Yes, I suspect that something like loup blanc's solution or something similarly computationally intensive might be necessary. Notice that it follows from making suitable linear substitutions and observing the simple sign changes of the terms (or rather, the lack thereof), we can see that any real solution must be in $[-1, 1]$, and perhaps this might lead to something doable by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to write the Sturm's sequence, cf. "Sturm's theorem" in

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)

or rather, to ask Maple or Mathematica to write it. It is a formal method (as a gcd calculation); therefore the calculations can be huge.

Here Maple gives

$\left[{x}^{14}+2\,{x}^{13}-{x}^{12}-4\,{x}^{11}-{x}^{10}+4\,{x}^{8}+6\,{x}^
{7}-4\,{x}^{6}-6\,{x}^{5}+4\,{x}^{4}+4\,{x}^{2}-8\,x+4,{x}^{13}+{
\frac {13}{7}}\,{x}^{12}-6/7\,{x}^{11}-{\frac {22}{7}}\,{x}^{10}-5/7\,
{x}^{9}+{\frac {16}{7}}\,{x}^{7}+3\,{x}^{6}-{\frac {12}{7}}\,{x}^{5}-{
\frac {15}{7}}\,{x}^{4}+{\frac {8}{7}}\,{x}^{3}+4/7\,x-4/7,-10+{x}^{12
}+9/5\,{x}^{11}-2/5\,{x}^{10}-{\frac {21}{5}}\,{x}^{8}-{\frac {131}{20
}}\,{x}^{7}+{\frac {133}{20}}\,{x}^{6}+{\frac {177}{20}}\,{x}^{5}-{
\frac {31}{4}}\,{x}^{4}-{\frac {42}{5}}\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {92}{5}}\,x-1/
4\,{x}^{9}+2/5\,{x}^{3},-{\frac {25}{4}}\,{x}^{9}-17\,{x}^{3}+{x}^{11}
+{\frac {41}{8}}\,{x}^{10}-{\frac {97}{8}}\,{x}^{8}+{\frac {57}{8}}\,{
x}^{7}+{\frac {89}{8}}\,{x}^{6}-{\frac {79}{8}}\,{x}^{5}+{\frac {15}{4
}}\,{x}^{4}+32\,{x}^{2}-17\,x,{\frac {128}{293}}-{x}^{10}+{\frac {661}
{293}}\,{x}^{8}-{\frac {77}{293}}\,{x}^{7}-{\frac {685}{293}}\,{x}^{6}
+{\frac {355}{293}}\,{x}^{5}-{\frac {278}{293}}\,{x}^{4}-{\frac {1472}
{293}}\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {488}{293}}\,x+{\frac {114}{293}}\,{x}^{9}+{
\frac {1128}{293}}\,{x}^{3},{x}^{9}+{\frac {34152}{79351}}\,{x}^{3}-{
\frac {2224}{79351}}\,{x}^{8}-{\frac {143283}{79351}}\,{x}^{7}+{\frac 
{23809}{79351}}\,{x}^{6}+{\frac {177833}{79351}}\,{x}^{5}-{\frac {
101647}{79351}}\,{x}^{4}-{\frac {255976}{79351}}\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {
316752}{79351}}\,x-{\frac {103400}{79351}},-{\frac {4874668}{2473535}}
-{x}^{8}-{\frac {3702696}{2473535}}\,{x}^{7}+{\frac {1102024}{2473535}
}\,{x}^{6}+{\frac {4719882}{2473535}}\,{x}^{5}+{\frac {13061}{107545}}
\,{x}^{4}-{\frac {712376}{2473535}}\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {5795756}{2473535}
}\,x-{\frac {2517376}{2473535}}\,{x}^{3},-{\frac {130644976}{71135621}
}\,{x}^{3}-{x}^{7}-{\frac {117877931}{71135621}}\,{x}^{6}+{\frac {
42199772}{71135621}}\,{x}^{5}+{\frac {191521943}{71135621}}\,{x}^{4}+{
\frac {34202204}{71135621}}\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {119672796}{71135621}}\,x-
{\frac {131248248}{71135621}},{\frac {4636190692}{845120667}}+{x}^{6}+
{\frac {469969805}{281706889}}\,{x}^{5}-{\frac {4887791734}{845120667}
}\,{x}^{4}+{\frac {1291091456}{281706889}}\,{x}^{2}-{\frac {9119197856
}{845120667}}\,x+{\frac {3667395556}{845120667}}\,{x}^{3},-{\frac {
118807258}{229387925}}\,{x}^{3}+{x}^{5}-{\frac {23751047557}{
17433482300}}\,{x}^{4}+{\frac {1733801327}{871674115}}\,{x}^{2}-{
\frac {6098757498}{4358370575}}\,x+{\frac {1595181704}{4358370575}},-{
\frac {14165381246176}{3678995429977}}+{x}^{4}+{\frac {148022761860}{
3678995429977}}\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {77449670408}{12730087993}}\,x-{\frac 
{12687975462712}{3678995429977}}\,{x}^{3},-{x}^{3}+{\frac {
67591683841151}{107354894758164}}\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {82833966032893}{
53677447379082}}\,x-{\frac {543419063876153}{429419579032656}},{\frac 
{3543406427639359}{2400254723765948}}+{x}^{2}-{\frac {1466258753587345
}{600063680941487}}\,x,x-{\frac {75792061996548545}{75819308999515908}
},-1\right]$

Comment: Thanks very much, I had heard about that method a long time ago but never used it (thus hadn't the idea to use it), and didn't know that computer algebra systems had this method.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of converting the Maple output to $\LaTeX$ using the Maple command $\texttt{latex()}$ (as you can see, it seems to treat fractions with single-digit entries differently).

Comment: I thought about a method but it had a flaw in it because I assumed implicitly that the function is convex.